# Error while using pattern API [ERROR: ('NoneType' object has no attribute 'title')]

Tags: python, python-2.7, api

```
from pattern.web import Wikipedia
from textblob import TextBlob
engine = Wikipedia(language="en")

find = raw_input("What is it ???")
article = engine.search(find , cached=True, timeout=30)
print article.title 
hippo = TextBlob(article.string.encode('utf-8').strip())
print hippo.noun_phrases
```

I am getting error of ['NoneType' object has no attribute 'title']
why does the `article = engine.search(find , cached=True, timeout=30)` take None value

Comment: `engine.search()` is returning `None` which is stored in the `article` variable. Later on it's being used as `article.title` and `None` does not have an attribute named `title`.

Comment: yeah but its returning WikipediaArticle(title=u'TITLE')

Comment: when there is no TextBlob

Comment: Is this your full code? I don't see how TextBlob could be causing that error unless something else is happening.

Comment: yes it is , i want to use 'article.source' , but it has error on 'article.title'

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I cannot reproduce this error. In this line

```
article = engine.search(find , cached=True, timeout=30)
```

The `engine` didn't find an article with that query and returned `None`. Could be a bad query, or network problems, who knows.

If I do this:

```
from pattern.web import Wikipedia

engine = Wikipedia(language="en")

article = engine.search("Django (web framework)" , cached=True, timeout=30)
print article.title
```

I get the article title `Django (web framework)`.

Check your input with `print(find)`, and check your network.

Comment: I tried the the exact keyword like ex : Django (web framework) , still same output and N/W is fine too

Comment: ' print find ' returns Django (web framework) , but variable ' article ' aint taking the value

Comment: Well I just copy your code and it works. Maybe upgrade the pattern library?

Comment: tried "bind = str(find)" then "article = engine.search(bind , cached=True, timeout=30) " , still same output

Comment: What if you - for the moment - hardcode your query into the search, like I did in the answer?

Comment: that works absolutely fine , but its not taking the find value , i cant hardcore it for the project , it should ask the value on the cmd prompt

Comment: Use `input()` instead of `raw_input()`?

Comment: tried this too but now m getting 'SyntaxError: invalid syntax'

Comment: is this code working on ur system , with the 'input()' option